# How to get the output of a matlab script in python

Tags: python, matlab, subprocess

I am performing a matlab calculation through python. For this purpose, I use the following command:

```
retcode=subprocess.call["matlab","-nosplash","nodesktop","-wait","-r","run('matlabscript.m')","quit;"])
```

by running this command line in python, a matlab session opens and I can start to execute the aforementioned script `'matlabscript.m'`. Is there a way to get the output of the execution of this script into python? retcode, does not contain anything unless a single number. I have tried to use subprocess.check_output instead, but I cannot get anything. Basically, when I execute the aforementioned sript a casename is going to be created and specified.

Comment: Have you tried `subprocess.Popen` with `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` and the `communicate` method?

Comment: @cdarke answers go in the answers box.

Comment: @AaronHall: it's not an answer because the question specifically requires `subprocess.call`, not `Popen`.

Comment: @cdarke read the source, same thing: https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/8667c26e2bec/Lib/subprocess.py#l552

Comment: I think that communicate method is when you would like to insert the sequence of commands to specify when the matlab script runs. Are you certain about the usage of this command?

Comment: @DomenicodiCugno: it can be used that way, but that would not be appropriate here as you say (see my post)

Comment: @AaronHall: fair enough

Comment: I think he either doesn't know what to do with the output, or his output is going to stderr.

Comment: If you know about `check_output()`; why do you use `call()`? To get non-empty output; print the results explicitly in your `matlabscript.m` script or configure matlab (if it is possible) to echo its internal output to its stdout.

Comment: Consider: if you put `1+1` into Python REPL then you see the output `2`. If you put `1+1` into a file e.g., `one_plus_one.py` and run it `python one_plus_one.py` then you see nothing. You have to print explicitly e.g., `print(1+1)` (`matlab` may use different functions for printing but the logic is the same).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use `Popen`.  I don't have matlab, so I can't test your exact command, but try this:

```
import subprocess

cmd = ["matlab", "-nosplash", "no desktop", "-wait", "r", "run('matlabscript.m')","quit;"]

proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
(output, error) = proc.communicate()

if error:
    print "error:", error

print "output:", output

# if you need this:
retcode = proc.returncode
```

If a huge amount of output is produced then this could potentially crash, its a judgement only you can make.

Note that `subprocess.communicate()` is also used for `stdin`.

Comment: I may need to clarify that the output that I need is whatever comes out or is typed into the cmd of matlab. It is this the information that I want to get returned into python. By the way, by following your method, the output I get is empty.

Comment: @DomenicodiCugno: I'm assuming your phrase "output" means stdout, the standard output stream.  If it is sent somewhere else then you will have to capture it some other way.  This could be why `check_output` does not work.  Did you get anything through the error (stderr) stream?  Can you confirm what you mean by output?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `subprocess.check_output` which will wait for the result:

```
subprocess.check_output(["matlab","-nosplash","nodesktop","-wait","-r","run('matlabscript.m')","quit;"])
```

Comment: I agree that this is a step in the right direction. But apparently "I have tried to use subprocess.check_output instead, but I cannot get anything", so something else is going on.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Matlab >= R2014b, you can simply use the [Matlab Engine for Python](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab-engine-for-python.html) provided by Mathworks.

```
>>> import matlab.engine
>>> worker = matlab.engine.start_matlab()
>>> a = worker.eval('rand(10,10)')
>>> print(a)
[[0.8147236863931789,0.15761308167754828,0.6557406991565868,0.7060460880196088,0.43874435965639824,0.27602507699857837,0.7512670593056529,0.8407172559836625,0.35165950706299676,0.07585428956306361],[0.9057919370756192,0.9705927817606157,0.035711678574189554,0.031832846377420676,0.3815584570930084,0.6797026768536748,0.2550951154592691,0.25428217897153105,0.8308286278962909,0.05395011866660715],[0.12698681629350606,0.9571669482429456,0.8491293058687771,0.27692298496088996,0.7655167881490024,0.6550980039738407,0.5059570516651424,0.8142848260688164,0.5852640911527243,0.5307975530089727],[0.9133758561390194,0.4853756487228412,0.9339932477575505,0.04617139063115394,0.7951999011370632,0.16261173519463057,0.699076722656686,0.2435249687249893,0.5497236082911395,0.7791672301020112],[0.6323592462254095,0.8002804688888001,0.6787351548577735,0.09713178123584754,0.1868726045543786,0.11899768155837664,0.8909032525357985,0.9292636231872278,0.91719366382981,0.934010684229183],[0.09754040499940952,0.14188633862721534,0.7577401305783334,0.8234578283272926,0.48976439578823106,0.49836405198214295,0.9592914252054443,0.34998376598480874,0.28583901882037355,0.12990620847373013],[0.2784982188670484,0.421761282626275,0.7431324681249162,0.694828622975817,0.4455862007108995,0.9597439585160811,0.5472155299638031,0.19659525043120818,0.7572002291107213,0.5688236608721927],[0.5468815192049838,0.9157355251890671,0.39222701953416816,0.31709948006086053,0.6463130101112646,0.3403857266661332,0.13862444282867914,0.25108385797603106,0.7537290942784953,0.4693906410582058],[0.9575068354342976,0.7922073295595544,0.6554778901775566,0.9502220488383549,0.7093648308580726,0.5852677509797773,0.14929400555905747,0.6160446761466392,0.38044584697535666,0.011902069501241397],[0.9648885351992765,0.959492426392903,0.17118668781156177,0.03444608050290876,0.7546866819823609,0.22381193949113698,0.25750825412373646,0.47328884890272926,0.5678216407252211,0.3371226443988815]]
```

As an alternative, switch to GNU Octave and simple use [Oct2Py](http://blink1073.github.io/oct2py/).